# silent installation process without messages

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-8, windows-xp

I often install software on my Windows machine. So I would like to install programs in "silent" mode - I mean, standardly when you run any installation of software, you must confirm few steps. I would like to be able to install any software on Windows with just running some kind of silent command and it should install any software without confirming (default dir, eula, etc.).

Does this magic "silent" command exist please?
Ideally universally working solution for Win XP/2008/7/8/10 and any installed software. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it depends on the company / person packaging the software and the installer. Some of the common "silent" installer flags are shown here: http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php

And as you can see on that page, each different installer type (and not including any custom ones that people made their own installer and not re-using the existing one) have different flags and how to install.

So no there is one-size-fit-all silent installer unfortunately, unless you somehow have all of them using one type of installer (all using MSI for example).